# Rails 4: ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to insert a gmap into my webpage and no matter what I always get `ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined`. Here's what I did so far:

- added `gem 'gmaps4rails'`, ran bundle install, restarted server
- added underscore to my app/assets/javascript folder
- added `//= require underscore
  //= require gmaps/google` to my application.js
- edited application and my view html (code below)
- added a custom js file called Gmap.js to my app/assets/javascript folder (code below)

my application.html.erb (just the head):

```
<head>
  <title><%= @page_title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <%= yield :scripts %>
</head>
```

my index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
        <div style='width: 800px;'>
            <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

my gmap.js

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks for the help

Here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Shooshte/ZIC) of the whole thing. Relevant file names are in the post.

Comment: you dont include gmapsrails in your assets

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file make sure you include js in the  section not at the bottom in the footer

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem and in my application.js I needed the javascripts to be called in a certain order. May this will help someone else

```
//= require vendor/underscore-min
//= require gmaps/google
//= require remastering/find_us
```